# What is the role/purpose of hidden variables in graphical models?

Tags: graphical-model, latent-variable

Is there a formal treatment of the role/power of latent/hidden variables in graphical models and other machine learning models (e.g., structural equation models)?

For example, the Restricted Boltzman Machine is a graphical model which is a compact representation of a probability distribution of $x$, but it is modeled as a joint distribution with a hidden variable $h$ (i.e., we model $p(x,h)$ instead of $p(x)$).  Why is $p(x,h)$ any more powerful than a suitable representation for $p(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden variables simplify the description of certain models.  They do not give any more modelling power.  For any model with hidden variables, there is an equivalent model without them.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out and also saw the same in this webpage: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html (under the title "Inventing new hidden nodes").  Now I understand hidden variables lower model complexity.